# Reading IIS log fields as they are written

Tags: asp.net, iis, httpmodule

I am writing a custom HttpModule for an ASP.NET application. I would like to be able to access the W3C fields that are written to the IIS log. It looks like the data structure [HTTP_LOG_FIELDS_DATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364537.aspx) is the relevant data structure.

Is there a way to access this log information immediately before or immediately after this is written to the log file? If this cannot be done in .NET, could this be done in C++?

(I am not looking to use Microsoft Log Parser.)

Answer (score -1):

<strike>See [Microsoft's Log Parser 2.2](http://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2010/04/log-parser-22) with a [link to how you can query, etc.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2010/03/25/analyze-your-iis-log-files-favorite-log-parser-queries.aspx)</strike>

Guess I completely missed that part...

- <strike>Unsure about `as they are written` re:</strike> *for each and every resource* requested ?
- How about the info you get from  [HttpRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx)

Hth..

Comment: I specifically stated in the question that I am not looking to use Microsoft Log Parser.

Comment: Hmmm..missed that. apologies. Deleting